# Bind color with Vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I want to give icon color with for loop. I have tried in this way. But getting no result. I know it's possible to bind style.

```
<v-tab v-for="navtab in navtabs" :key="navtab">
    <v-icon color="{{ navtab.color }}">{{ navtab.icon }}</v-icon>
</v-tab>
```

Data property:

```
<script>
export default {
    data () {
      return {
      navtabs: [
        {
          icon: 'info',
          name: 'About Book',
          color: 'teal darken-2'
        },

        {
          icon: 'favorite',
          name: 'Specification',
          color: 'orange darken-2'
        }
      ]
   }
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Is `darken-2` a color or css class?

Comment: color name. You can see any example in vuetify.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not use:

```
<v-icon color="{{ navtab.color }}">{{ navtab.icon }}</v-icon>
```

Instead, **bind** the variable color:

```
<v-icon :color="navtab.color">{{ navtab.icon }}</v-icon>
```